# Determine the number of iterations for a For Next loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am taking Applied/Advanced Financial Analysis class and our assignment this week is to display an amortization schedule in a messagebox using 3 (or 4) input boxes.

I reached out to my professor, but I am not knowledgable enough to follow the directions.

I can get all four input boxes to show up and the messagebox as well, but it will not display the loop. I am trying to store the calculation for the loop in a variable, but I have no clue how to do that.

```vb
Sub PaymentScheduleCalculator()

Dim PV As Single '10000
Dim years As Single '2
Dim frequency As Double '12
Dim rate As Variant '4% APR

Dim Ppmt As Double
Dim Ipmt As Double
Dim Pmt As Single 'for pmt after each year

Dim i As Integer 'designation for loop
  
Dim Temp As Integer
Dim TempVars!

For i = 1 To n * frequency
    Pmt = PV * rate / frequency
    TempVars! = Temp & vbNewLine & i & _
               vbTab & FormatCurrency(PV, 2) & _
               vbTab & FormatCurrency(Pmt, 2) & _
               vbTab & FormatCurrency(Ipmt, 2) & _
               vbTab & FormatCurrency(-Ipmt, 2)
               PV = PV - Pmt + Ipmt
Next i
  
PV = InputBox("How much money do you want to borrow?", "Payment Calculator", 10000)
years = InputBox("If you borrow " & FormatCurrency(PV) & " - how many years do want to borrow the money for?", "Payment Calculator", 2)

rate = InputBox("If you borrow " & FormatCurrency(PV) & " for " & years & " years, " & "what interest rate are you paying?", "Payment Calculator", 0.04)
If Right(rate, 1) = "%" Then
    rate = Val(Left(rate, Len(rate) - 1) / 100)
Else
    rate = rate
End If

frequency = InputBox("If you borrow " & FormatCurrency(PV) & " at " & FormatPercent(rate) & "," & " for " & years & " years, " & _
"how many payment intervals are there per year?", "Payment Calculator", 12)
'runs fine until here but does not display the loop
            
MsgBox "Loan Amount " & FormatCurrency(PV) & _
  vbNewLine & "Number of Payments " & years * frequency & _
  vbNewLine & "Interest Rate " & FormatPercent(rate) & _
  vbNewLine & _
  vbNewLine & "PMT # " & vbTab & "Balance " & vbTab & "Payment " & vbTab & 
  "Interest " & vbTab & "Capital " & _
  vbNewLine & RepeatCalc, , "Payment Calculator"

End Sub
```

Comment: Should we assume that `frequency` and `n` are both zero since you did not give them a value? `For i = 1 to 0` means the loop will not run.

Comment: Put a break point on the line where the loops starts, then you can check your variables before letting it continue.

Comment: wait - frequency is how ever many payments there are in the amortization schedule - so if the loan is idk 5 years and its biannual, there would be a frequency of 2 equaling 10 payments. The value comes from an input box further down.

Comment: regarding the breakpoint - it runs. like the whole thing runs, displays input and output textboxes, just not the calculation that is inside the loop. Does that make sense? So like I could take the whole loop out and it would still run the exact same as now and display the same input and output messageboxes. So its like the loop is invisible.

Comment: Further down? The need initial values then. The loop should not be dependent on values that change inside the loop.

Comment: The loop isn't running because `frequency * n` equals zero when it gets to that line.

Comment: so the loop needs to move down after the "frequency =" ? I just did that, moved it down between the frequency and the msgbox, and nothing happened.

Comment: Presumably, yes. They need to have values before you can check/use their values. Make sense?

Comment: Instead of "nothing happened" - use break points - use F8 to step thru line by line. Check your variables as you go.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense - just like order of operations. But its like when I run it the loop just gets skipped over. (Also thank you so much for even responding - I really appreciate it!)

Comment: It skips the loop that starts at 1 because you are telling it to stop at 0, and 1 is greater than 0.

Comment: oh! that makes sense! So do I just change the "1 to n*frequency" to "0 to n*frequency"?

Comment: That would run the loop once.... and `i` will be equal to zero. So if that's what your intent is...

Comment: look, I am sorry, as my username says, I am a noob. this is my first ever exposure to vba and/or coding in general -  I have no clue what I am doing. Is there any way to dumb this down so I get where I am going wrong? I understand that I messed up the order of operations, that makes perfect sense, but I don't understand where I am going wrong with the loop.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement

Comment: What's that `TempVars!`? Declare the variables nicely. `Dim TempVars As String` and use `Debug.Print TempVars` right after, if your intent is to see what's happening in the loop. Move the loop to a place after you have collected the values from the input boxes after the line `runs fine until...`. No other value than the initial 0 is ever assigned to `Ipmt`: figure it out. Use `As Integer` for whole numbers. Not sure what `n` is supposed to be but `years` looks like a candidate. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to identify undeclared variables.

Comment: Yeah, i figured I went wrong with the declaring of the variables and braX had pointed it out yesterday as well, I just didn't know how to fix it. Thank you for taking the time to respond. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code...as others have pointed out as well.

First of, you want to run a `For...next` loop by using

```
For i = 1 To n * frequency

    'some code

next
```

The loop is initiated before those variables 'n' & 'frequency' have been assigned a value. Although your intention was to set 'frequency' by means of an Input box, 'n' is not set anywhere and will hence always be 0. The result is therefore in essence that the loop reads:

```
For i = 1 To 0 * 12 'which results in the loop not running at all

    'some code

next
```

So, properly set 'n' to whatever it needs to be or provide an input dialog for it.

Moreover, the actual intention of this loop is to extend the displayed text in the message box.

If you want to do that, you will need to start building the string first.
According to your code your text should begin with:

```
"Loan Amount " & FormatCurrency(PV) & _
    vbNewLine & "Number of Payments " & years * frequency & _
    vbNewLine & "Interest Rate " & FormatPercent(rate) & _
    vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & "PMT # " & vbTab & "Balance " & vbTab & "Payment " & vbTab & "Interest " & vbTab & "Capital "
```

So if you assign that text to a variable you can then extend the text using the loop, like so:

```
Dim msgText As String
msgText = "Loan Amount " & FormatCurrency(PV) & _
    vbNewLine & "Number of Payments " & years * frequency & _
    vbNewLine & "Interest Rate " & FormatPercent(rate) & _
    vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & "PMT # " & vbTab & "Balance " & vbTab & "Payment " & vbTab & "Interest " & vbTab & "Capital "
    
    'now the loop extends 'msgText'
    For i = 1 To n * frequency
        Pmt = PV * rate / frequency
        msgText = msgText & vbNewLine & Str(i) & _
                       vbTab & FormatCurrency(PV, 2) & _
                       vbTab & FormatCurrency(Pmt, 2) & _
                       vbTab & FormatCurrency(Ipmt, 2) & _
                       vbTab & FormatCurrency(-Ipmt, 2)
        PV = PV - Pmt + Ipmt
    Next i

msgText = msgText & vbNewLine & RepeatCalc
```

Once that is completed, the whole string is contained in variable `msgText`
You can then initiate the `MsgBox` with that text.

```
MsgBox msgText, vbOKOnly, "Payment Calculator"
```

One more thing, you have an InputBox for `rate` and you seem to try and remove the '%' sign at the end of the string in case somebody puts in a percentage with a sign. (good thinking in itself..:-))

Although this works, what it ends up with is a `String` type variable and, as `rate` is declared as `Variant` it has no issues with that...
But it will screw up your calculation in your `For..next` loop, as `Pmt = PV * rate / frequency` can only work using values (i.e. Double\Integer etc.)

What you should do is declare `rate` as a `Double` and ensure that the result of your '%' removal will be converted to a `Double` value by means of -for example- using `CDbl(Val(Left(rate, Len(rate) - 1) / 100))`

So, your code, with some amendments should look more or less like the below. Mind you, you may have to ensure that all variables (including 'n') are properly set to ensure the calculation is correct. As, for example, `Ipmt` is not calculated anywhere...

Altered code:

```
Sub PaymentScheduleCalculator()

Dim PV As Single '10000
Dim years As Single '2
Dim frequency As Double '12
Dim rate As Double '4% APR
Dim strRate As String

Dim Ppmt As Double
Dim Ipmt As Double
Dim Pmt As Single 'for pmt after each year

Dim i As Integer 'designation for loop
  
Dim Temp As Integer

n = 1 'has to be properly set to relevant value?
  
PV = InputBox("How much money do you want to borrow?", "Payment Calculator", 10000)
years = InputBox("If you borrow " & FormatCurrency(PV) & " - how many years do want to borrow the money for?", "Payment Calculator", 2)

strRate = InputBox("If you borrow " & FormatCurrency(PV) & " for " & years & " years, " & "what interest rate are you paying?", "Payment Calculator", 0.04)
        If Right(strRate, 1) = "%" Then
            rate = CDbl(Val(Left(strRate, Len(strRate) - 1) / 100))
        Else
            rate = CDbl(strRate)
        End If

frequency = InputBox("If you borrow " & FormatCurrency(PV) & " at " & FormatPercent(rate) & "," & " for " & years & " years, " & _
"how many payment intervals are there per year?", "Payment Calculator", 12)

Dim msgText As String
msgText = "Loan Amount " & FormatCurrency(PV) & _
    vbNewLine & "Number of Payments " & years * frequency & _
    vbNewLine & "Interest Rate " & FormatPercent(rate) & _
    vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & "PMT # " & vbTab & "Balance " & vbTab & "Payment " & vbTab & "Interest " & vbTab & "Capital "
    
    'now extends the 'msgText' variable
    For i = 1 To n * frequency
        Pmt = PV * rate / frequency
        msgText = msgText & vbNewLine & Str(i) & _
                       vbTab & FormatCurrency(PV, 2) & _
                       vbTab & FormatCurrency(Pmt, 2) & _
                       vbTab & FormatCurrency(Ipmt, 2) & _
                       vbTab & FormatCurrency(-Ipmt, 2)
        PV = PV - Pmt + Ipmt
    Next i

msgText = msgText & vbNewLine & RepeatCalc

MsgBox msgText, vbOKOnly, "Payment Calculator"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! And especially thank you for the detailed explanation and helping me learn. I really appreciate it so much. I fully thought that n was just part of a formula, which is why I didn't declare it - duh! That makes so much sense now!

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help. If this has answered your question then mark the answer as the correct answer, it helps SO stay up-to-date by minimizing non-answered questions.

Comment: @Excelnoob, by the way, I think the 'n' in your calculation should be 'years' value? That would make sense from the perspective of the actual calculation but also because in your code you don't actually use 'years' value anywhere?